# How to test for convergence (smoothness of Pareto front) in DEAP

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, deap

In the DEAP algorithms ([see documentation here](http://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/algo.html)), I notice that we need to specify the the number of generations (NGEN). I was advised that convergence has been achieved if the Pareto curve is smooth.

It is possible to monitor for convergence by specifying a "smoothness" value in the stats. However, I'm still confused about how to define "smoothness". For example, consider the [Knapsack problem specified here](http://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/examples/ga_knapsack.html). How do we monitor for smoothness in this example? In general, how can I monitor for convergence in DEAP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the logbook statistics to monitor various measures. 
Just define "smoothness" as an observable and quit iterating as soon as it hits your desired value.

```
def smoothness(pop):
    pareto = tools.ParetoFront()
    pareto.update(pop)
    return xxx       # <-- need to fill you measure here

stats = tools.Statistics()
stats.register("smoothness", smoothness)
```

If you are using deap for symbolic regression you might want to have a look at https://github.com/Ambrosys/glyph . It is still in its early stages though. Glyph is build on top of deap currently and tries to hide the boilerplate code. You can set custom break conditions too: https://github.com/Ambrosys/glyph/blob/master/glyph/application.py#L131

Comment: How do I define smoothness? I can see that I can monitor the average, minimum, and maximum fitness at each generation. How do I specify "smoothness"?

Comment: I edited my answer above. How you define smoothness depends on your problem/domain.

Comment: Alright. A little help though with defining smoothness. For example, consider the Knapsack problem: http://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/examples/ga_knapsack.html
How would I define the smoothness for such?